# Redirecting text data from file to stdin c# windows

Tags: c#, windows, file, stdin, redirect

How can I redirect data from some text file to the C# program's stdin? Via some code or command prompt (in Windows)? I've tried redirecting it in command prompt like this: input.txt > program.exe > output.txt (like in linux), but that's not working. Also tried it this way:

```
string path = @"D:\input.txt";
// Open the file to read from. 
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
{
    string s = "";
    using (StreamWriter stdinput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardInput()))
    {
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            stdinput.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But this didn't work either. It crushes with the following error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Stream was not writable."

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Using command redirection operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

```
 program.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```