# Provide input to an .exe file from a text file

Tags: cmd

When I run an a.exe file as below it is running fine:

```
C:\forc>a.exe 'iss mac'

6
```

(Output is 6)

How to provide this input from a text file?

I tried the below but no luck:

```
C:\forc>a.exe < input.txt
C:\forc>a.exe 'input.txt'
```

Kindly help.

Comment: depends strongly, how your `exe` handles input. Your attempt is one of the possibilities. Another one is `type input.txt|a.exe`

Comment: maybe `a.exe /?` reveals the secret?

Answer (score 1):

the only time that you will be able to pass file contents into a program is when the program accepts a filename in the **command line arguments** or if the program is designed in a way that lets it read all the contents of the **standard input** stream.  For example, in C#,  you would treat `Console.In` in the same way you would treat a file input stream (read lines, chars, etc)

**in conclusion**
the program must directly support consuming data from standard input in order to use the < redirection. Standard Input is NOT the same as a command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can send input to `a.exe` depends entirely on `a.exe`. You will need to read the documentation for `a.exe`, or ask its author, to determine whether what you want to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

From [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991395/10305444) answer :

[Using command redirection operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

```
 program.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```