# VS Code: Input and Output with files instead of terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual studio code for C++ and my code is using simple user input (`getline`, `cin`).
I have more than 50K test inputs, some portion of which I use to paste in the terminal as user input. The problem is both input and output are mixed, the problem amplifies if I have a lot of input and it is not possible to distinguish.

If there is a way to have all the inputs in a text file and the output is exported to another file. I read somewhere that tasks.json could be useful in this. How can that be useful in this scenario?

Comment: You should be able to run your executable from command prompt and redirect the output to a file like this: myExecutable.exe > output.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991361/redirecting-text-data-from-file-to-stdin-c-sharp-windows

Comment: @NO_GUI I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate of a non-vscode question. the question you suggested is not the same as this one. And plus, it's C#, whereas this question is motivated by a C++ use-case.

Answer (score 1):

In the working directory(folder you are saving cpp files) add two files one for input (input.txt) and other for output (output.txt) ,
then in the your file that contain your c++ source code add these two lines:
1-
`freopen("input.txt" ,"r" ,stdin) ;` ===> input.txt this is the name of the input file, "r" short for read, stdin stands for standard input which is the keyboard in this case.

2-
`freopen("output.txt" , "w" ,stdout) ;` ==> also output.txt this is the name of the output file,  "w" short for write, stdout stands for standard output which is the screen in this case.

If you are using online judge, instead you should write these lines to avoid errors:

```
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE  
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tasks, *shell-specific* file redirection syntax and features are supported if you use the `shell` task type- but not for the `process` task type (pretty intuitive). Consult your shell's documentation for what syntax it uses for file redirection.

You can also just use your shell-of-choice's syntax and features for file redirection in a shell in [VS Code's integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics).

Note that for run/debug, your debug support extension(s) may (or may not) also support some form of file redirection syntax ([related docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target)) in the launch config.

If you're looking for a non-shell solution, then it pretty much comes down to program-specific support for selecting input and output files, in which case you should consult the program's manual / documentation to see if it has such commandline options.